# Find most common words from set of sentences in Python

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have 5 sentences in a np.array and I want to find the most common n number of words that appear. For example if n was 3 I would want the 3 most common words. I have an example below:

```
0    oh i am she cool though might off her a brownie lol
1    so trash wouldnt do colors better tweet
2    love monkey brownie as much as a tweet
3    monkey get this tweet around i think
4    saw a brownie to make me some monkey
```

If n was 3 I would like it to print the words: brownie, monkey, tweet. Is there a straighforward way to do something like this?

Comment: Yes. The most straightforward way to approach a complex task is to break it into simpler ones. Even when I don't know how to solve a problem, I can always guess one step. What would the first step be? Once you understand that, you'll know more about the problem as a whole.

Comment: Once you've studied the problem enough to write some code, you'll also have done approximately enough research to ask a well-received question here, if you get stuck on something in particular. (We generally expect the asker to do as much work on their own as is possible before posting a question.) In particular, this question is too broad to answer well on Stack Overflow, since there is no one right way to answer it. I hope that I have helped you move forward. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the help of `CountVectorizer` as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

A = np.array(["oh i am she cool though might off her a brownie lol", 
              "so trash wouldnt do colors better tweet", 
              "love monkey brownie as much as a tweet",
              "monkey get this tweet around i think",
              "saw a brownie to make me some monkey" ])

n = 3
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(A)

vocabulary = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
ind  = np.argsort(X.toarray().sum(axis=0))[-n:]

top_n_words = [vocabulary[a] for a in ind]

print (top_n_words)
['tweet', 'monkey', 'brownie']
```